# How to store sorted records in python, with log (n) access time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to store records arranged in ascending order, with `log(n)` access time. I come from C++ background and if I had to use C++, I would have gone for `std::map` which implements red-black tree internally. This guaranties the records to always be stored in ascending order of the keys, and also guaranties `log(n)` access time. But what's the best way to do this in Python3.5?

One way to solve this problem will be to use the `bintrees` library, but is there a dedicated library for storing sorted records?

Comment: I believe a you might want to take a look at `heapq`, which is part of the standard library. Python maps, i.e. `dict`s are hash-maps, so are inherently unordered.

Comment: Alternitively, use the [this](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sortedcontainers.SortedDict) library.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, [OrderedDict - python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), no idea about access time though.

Comment: @najjarammar `OrderedDict` maintains *insertion order*. The OP requires the dict to be *sorted*. You could manually sort an `OrderedDict` each time you add to it, but that isn't going to be efficient. I believe the `sortedcollections` library is the right way to go, and it is pretty well tested/maintained AFAICT. And by the way, `OrderedDict` access time is constant.

Comment: This : http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sortedcontainers.SortedDict was what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @Sreram yeah, I'm reading about the implementation, and it seems well thought out. Apparently, it is written in pure Python which is pretty cool!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Heaps aren't really ordered, either. They allow constant time access to the *smallest* (or largest) item in the collection, and log-time removal of the same. Access to arbitrary items is O(n) (you just have to walk the entire heap to find your target).

Comment: @chepner yeah, you are right. I think `sortedcontainers` is the way to go.

Comment: @chepner anyway, I think I was originally thinking of [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html) anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest using `bisect` if the data is mostly read-only.

Comment: Before the last edit to the question, I had said `bintrees` library was not compatible with Python3.5, but I was wrong. I didn't know that I had to use pip3 for installing packages to Python3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) which can allow you maintain an always sorted data-structures (list, dict, dictWithKeys, set).

You can install using
`pip install sortedcontainers`

Here is a quick example

```
import sortedcontainers
g = {'B': ['A', 'C'],
     'C': ['D'],
    'A': ['B', 'C'],
     'D': [],
     }

l = sortedcontainers.SortedDict(g)

>>> l
SortedDict(None, 1000, {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['A', 'C'], 'C': ['D'], 'D': []})
>>> l['G']=['A','B']
>>> l
SortedDict(None, 1000, {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['A', 'C'], 'C': ['D'], 'D': [], 'G': ['A', 'B']})
>>> l['E']=['C','D','G']
>>> l
SortedDict(None, 1000, {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['A', 'C'], 'C': ['D'], 'D': [], 'E': ['C', 'D', 'G'], 'G': ['A', 'B']})
>>>
```

Comment: @Sreram this library is available and tested on Python 3.

Comment: @sreram : As per documentation  the library is  Tested on CPython 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and PyPy 5.1+, PyPy3 2.4+ .

Comment: @Anil_M and @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, sorry about that. I didn't know I had to use `pip3` for installing packages to Python3.x.